# Why is no ReferenceError being thrown if a variable is used before it’s declared?

Tags: javascript, variable-declaration, referenceerror, hoisting

I’m trying to wrap my head around the behavior of reference errors thrown in JavaScript.

In the following example, a `ReferenceError` is thrown at the second line, and execution breaks:

```
var obj = {};
obj.func1 = func2;

alert('Completed');
```

Whereas in this example, the code completes successfully, though `obj.func1` remains `undefined`:

```
var obj = {};
obj.func1 = func2;

var func2 = function() {
    alert('func2');
};

alert('Completed');
```

My assumption was that an error would be thrown at the second line just the same, and when that wasn’t the case, I’d have expected `obj.func1` to properly reference `func2`, but I’ve been double blind-sided. So what exactly is going on here?

Comment: [Function Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting) and [Variable Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: @epascarello: There is no function hoisting with function expressions; only function *statements* are hoisted. This is `var` hoisting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` is hoisted; the variable exists throughout the current scope. Thus, the second example is equivalent to:

```
var obj;
var func2;

obj = {};
obj.func1 = func2;
func2 = function() {
    alert('func2');
}

alert('Completed');
```

Thus, when you do the assignment, The name `func2` is known, but `undefined`. In the first example, it is unknown, which raises `ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to Javascript variable declaration "hoisting".

A variable declared with `var` is visible everywhere in the function, so there's no `Reference Error`. However, it doesn't actually receive its value until you execute the statement that initializes it. So your second example is equivalent to:

```
var func2;
var obj = {};
obj.func1 = func2;

func2 = function() {
    alert('func2');
};

alert('Completed');
```

In this rewrite, you can see that the variable exists when you perform the assignment to `obj.func1`. But since it doesn't yet have a value, you assign `undefined` to `obj.func1`. Assigning to `func2` later doesn't change that.

Comment: Any reason the initialization of `obj` is coupled with its declaration? I understand since it'd occur immediately after anyway there'd be no practical difference, but is this a literal translation?

Comment: He's not referencing `obj` until after it's initialized, so there's effectively no difference between initializing it during the declaration or afterward. So I didn't bother rewriting that part, since it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: I guess I'm just raising concern whether your example obscures the behavior a bit if the idea is that *declarations* exclusively are hoisted.

Comment: The distinction between declaration and initialization only matters if you try to use the variable before the declaration. If all the uses are after, there's no difference, so it's not necessary to show that rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Your func2 variable is not visible. That's why obj.func1 remains undefined.

```js
var obj = {};
var func2 = function() {
    alert('func2');
    return "Test";
};
    
obj.func1 = func2;
   
alert('Completed');
```

Comment: I'm well aware defining `func2` before assigning `func1` would have resolved the error. This wasn't a real problem, just something I found peculiar during some tinkering.